# Calling a method in a class in each other method

Tags: java

I have a method that I want to be called each time one of the other methods is called.  I dont want to have to explicitely call it each time.  Is there a way to have the other methods naturally call that method before executing its own code?

If I have a method thats called isThere() and I want it called in each other method, I dont want to have isThere() written in each method.  I was hoping there would an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

You should look into [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) - Aspect Oriented Programming.

Since you are using Java, I recommend you to take a look at [AspectJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AspectJ).

Answer (score 0):

You could access all other methods through another method, which first calls there, and then uses a parameter you passed to it to identify which method you want it to use, using a switch statement or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look into [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), which may also solve your problem a bit differently. Read the Wikipedia page linked here. Alternatively, you can read the Observer pattern from the Head First Design Pattern book.